# Is there a way to record sound with a program that runs on both Android OS and iOS?

Tags: android, audio, ios, audio-recording

I would like to compare the sound capturing capabilities on Android and iOS smartphones. Therefore, I am looking for a current solution for capturing audio that can be used on both Android and iOS devices.

Comment: Do you have a budget you are willing to spend on this?

Comment: Sure. I was hoping to find Audacity or open-source recording apps, but it seems there's nothing like that on both platforms.

Answer (score 1):

Rev has an audio and voice recorder for both Android and iOS. You can find it [here](https://www.rev.com/voicerecorder).

Comment: This looks good. Can you confirm that audio captured on Android can be played on iOS and vice versa?